# Differential of exponential function

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic, semi-riemannian-geometry

I have the following theorem and proof in my lecture, which I don't quite understand:

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $p \in M$. Then it holds that

$(d \exp _p)_0=: T_0 T_pM \cong T_pM \rightarrow T_pM$ is the identity.

On the proof it says:
 Since $\exp(tv)= \gamma_v(t)$ for $v \in T_pM$, it holds
$$(d  \exp _p)_0 (v)= \biggl.\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} \biggr|_0  \exp (tv)=v$$
 ($\gamma_v$ is the unique maximal geodesic with $\gamma^{'}(0)=v$).

Now what I don't understand:

- The exponential function is only defined on a neighboorhood of $0$ in $TM$ right, so $(d \exp_p)_0: T_0 D$ where $D \subset T_pM$, right?
- I don't understand the proof at all, where does the $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ come from?

Can somebody explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exponential map is indeed defined in a neighborhood, but it is a neighborhood around the point $p\in M$, not $0$. Also note that $T_0 D = T_0 (T_p M)$, it is just the same tangent space.

First one just uses the definition of the differential. Note that $c:(-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to T_p M: t \mapsto tv$ is a curve in $T_p M$ and its derivative $c'(0) = v$ is the tangent vector $v$ in $T_0 (T_p M)$. If we plug this curve in the exponential function and then take the derivative, we obtain the differential. It might be more correct to write $\frac{d}{dt}$ instead of $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$, since there is only dependency on $t$.

Secondly, note that $\exp(tv) = \gamma_v(t)$, i.e. the unique maximal geodesic with $\gamma'_v(0)=v$. So 
 $$
   \biggl. \frac{d}{dt}\biggr|_0 \exp(tv) = \biggl. \frac{d}{dt}\biggr|_0 \gamma_v(t) = \gamma'_v(0) = v. 
 $$

Comment: Thanks already for the answer! Can you maybe explain to me how we identify $v \in T_pM$ with $v \in T_0 (T_pM)$?

Comment: Well, we regard $T_p M$ as a manifold. By the definition of a tangent vector as the velocity of a curve on $T_p M$, $c'(0)=v$ lies in $T_0 (T_p M)$.

Comment: I see that it's the intuitive way to derivate the curve but in my definition we have the tangent vector defined by a curve as the following: $v = \gamma^{'}(0)$ $\Leftrightarrow $ $v(f)= \dfrac{d (f \circ \gamma)}{dt}(t_0)$ and I just can't see why this is the same here

Comment: Ok. Note that the tangent space $T_p M$ as a vector space is just $\mathbb{R}^n$. And the tangent space $T_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ at $0$ can be identified with $\mathbb{R}^n$ itself (using just the identity map).

Comment: Yes, that is something which is so trivial for everybody but not for me, why is $T_pM $ just $\mathbb{R}^n$? Do we identify a tangent vector $\sum_i v_i \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ with the vector $(x_i)_i$?

Comment: If you regard tangent vectors as velocities of curves, then this is not so straightforward. In order to show that $T_p M$ is a vector space, one shows that one can also regard tangent vectors as derivations at $p$ of the smooth functions of $M$ (see [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space#Definition_via_derivations)). Once you know this, it is easy to show the tangent space is a vector space. And finally, any vector space of dimension $n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Thank you for your patience! Actually the definition via derivations is the one introduced in my lecture so I understand that it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ but in a case like this I would need to know the exact form of the isomorphism to really understand the proof.. another question, using the definition via derivations, how can we identify $T_0 (\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98408/discussion-between-ernie060-and-user1).